# Can you addWizardPage on Uninstaller (QtInstallerFramework)?

Tags: javascript, qt, windows-installer, uninstallation, qt-installer

I am using `QtInstallerFramework` and I am trying to add custom page when **uninstalling** the app.

I have `custompage.ui`  file(simple text) and I am adding it in my `package.xml`:

```
<UserInterfaces>
        <UserInterface>custompage.ui</UserInterface>
</UserInterfaces>
```

And this is how I am using it in my `componentscript.js`:

```
Component.prototype.componentLoaded = function ()
{
    installer.addWizardPage(component, "CustomPage", QInstaller.ReadyForInstallation)
}
```

The problem is that the page is displayed only when I install the application. When I uninstall it, CustomPage is not displayed.

Also, with another approach, if I try to add the customized page in my `controlscript.js` like this:

```
Controller.prototype.ReadyForInstallationPageCallback = function ()
{
    try {
        installer.addWizardPage(component, "CustomPage", QInstaller.ReadyForInstallation);
    }
    catch (e) {
        QMessageBox.warning("QMessageBox", "", e, QMessageBox.Ok);
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
ReferenceError: component is not defined
```

So, it looks like the component is not loaded at all when the application is uninstalled.
And from [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/ifw-customizing-installers.html#adding-pages) we **can add custom pages only in components xml** file with `<UserInterfaces>` tag.
Does this mean that we can not use custom gui pages in the uninstaller or I am missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During installation, `package.xml` and `componentscript.js` are in full effect, allowing for dynamic addition of wizard pages.
However, during uninstallation, the framework does not process [component scripts](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/scripting.html) in the same manner, which is why you see that custom pages do not appear.

```bash
[Installer/Uninstaller Process]
┌────────────────────┐   ┌──────────────────────────┐   ┌─────────────────────────┐
│ package.xml        │   │ componentscript.js       │   │ installscript.qs        │
│  └─ UserInterfaces │──►│  └─ addWizardPage(...)   │──►│  └─ Conditionall        │
└────────────────────┘   └──────────────────────────┘   │    modify wizard        │
            │                              ▲            └─────────────────────────┘
            │                              │                        ▲
            └──────────────────────────────┘                        │
                         Installation Process                       │
                                                            Uninstallation Process
```

You should use [`installscript.qs`](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/qtinstallerframework-startmenu-example.html#creating-the-example-package-information-file) to inject custom logic that runs during *both* installation and uninstallation (as [in this example](https://github.com/qtproject/installer-framework/blob/db2e634513036af4376d002567ef0f006ea6cc75/examples/registerfileextension/packages/org.qtproject.ifw.example.registerfileextension/meta/installscript.qs)).
Since this script is executed in both contexts, it is the ideal place to conditionally apply modifications for the uninstallation process.
It can distinguish between installation and uninstallation through conditional checks, enabling specific actions during the uninstallation phase.

Use [`installer.isUninstaller()`](https://github.com/qtproject/installer-framework/blob/db2e634513036af4376d002567ef0f006ea6cc75/doc/scripting-api/console.qdoc#L38-L41) to determine if the uninstallation process is underway, and then proceed with custom logic for adding or modifying wizard pages.

You can add custom pages through `installer.addWizardPage` for the installation process.
For uninstallation, consider *modifying* *existing* pages or using [available hooks](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/scripting.html#installer-hooks) in `installscript.qs` to interact with the uninstallation process.

In `installscript.qs`:

```js
function Controller() {
    // Constructor for script
}

Controller.prototype.IntroductionPageCallback = function() {
    if (installer.isUninstaller()) {
        // Custom logic for uninstallation, e.g., modifying the Introduction page
    }
}
```

---

> so my only option is modifying existing pages(probably with accessing the `gui.currentPageWidget()`) and adding/removing properties/objects from that page objects.

Yes, something like:

```js
function Controller() {
}

Controller.prototype.IntroductionPageCallback = function() {
    if (installer.isUninstaller()) {
        // Access the current page displayed in the uninstaller wizard
        var currentPage = gui.currentPageWidget();
        
        if (currentPage) {
            // Example modification: Change a label text on the current page
            // Note: That requires knowing the specific object names and structure of the UI
            if (currentPage.findChild("QLabel", "YourLabelObjectName")) {
                currentPage.findChild("QLabel", "YourLabelObjectName").text = "Custom text for the uninstallation process";
            }

            // Example: Adjust visibility of a specific element based on a condition
            var specificCondition = true; // Replace this with your actual condition
            if (specificCondition && currentPage.findChild("QWidget", "YourWidgetObjectName")) {
                currentPage.findChild("QWidget", "YourWidgetObjectName").visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. I modified the [example with the installscript](https://github.com/qtproject/installer-framework/blob/db2e634513036af4376d002567ef0f006ea6cc75/examples/registerfileextension/packages/org.qtproject.ifw.example.registerfileextension/meta/installscript.qs#L51) and set `addWizardPageItem` to be evaluated if `installer.isUninstaller()` is true, but still component scripts are not loaded when uninstalling the app.

Comment: Also about your last example about custom logic for uninstallation, if I call `addWizardPageItem` from controller script, I am getting reference error because addWizardPageItem [requires component as parameter](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/scripting-installer.html#addWizardPageItem-method) and it looks like component is not accessible from controller script.

Comment: @peco `addWizardPageItem()`? The all idea of my answer is to point out (from what I understand of the documentation) that you cannot add/remove components during the uninstallation phase. You can still aim to modify or interact with existing pages within the uninstaller's workflow. That can be done by accessing and manipulating the properties of wizard pages already present in the uninstaller's sequence.

Comment: Aha okay, so my only option is modifying existing pages(probably with accessing the `gui.currentPageWidget()`) and adding/removing properties/objects from that page objects.

Comment: @peco Exactly. Something like the example I just added to the answer.